# Finding ServiceName in PreAuthorizationMiddleware of Ocelot Api-Gateway

Tags: .net-core, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot

Imagine a scenario (I know it seems odd but unfortunately it’s real!) that clients want to use one upstream (e.g., http://api.qwe.com/v1/sms) to send SMS with some SMS providers, but in the background it automatically identifies the related subservice based on the `scope` parameter on the JWT token and not to use separated URLs for each one (e.g., …/sms/provider1 - …/sms/provider2). So I decided to add this functionality into the Ocelot API Gateway (maybe it’s wrong, actually I’m not sure…) because I think it might be better to handle requests on API-Gateway instead of a middle-Service or microservices.

There are some samples that says we can add this functionality to the PreAuthorizationMiddleware. For example:

```
    var config = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
    {
        PreAuthorizationMiddleware = async (httpContext, next) =>
        {
            var claims = httpContext.User.Claims;
            if (claims != null)
            {
                var scopes = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "scope").Select(x => x.Value);
                if (scopes != null)
                {
                    // Override the downstream request settings
                    var downstreamRequest = httpContext.Items.DownstreamRequest();
                    downstreamRequest.Host = downstreamRequest.Host;
                    downstreamRequest.Port = downstreamRequest.Port;
                    downstreamRequest.Scheme = downstreamRequest.Scheme;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("Ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    builder.Services.AddOcelot(config).AddConsul();
```

As it shows, they use `downstreamRequest.Host` and `downstreamRequest.Port` to find sub-services, but what should you do if you use Consul as service discovery?

As you know, in this situation Ocelot will use service discovery with ServiceName to find sub-services. **The main question is how can I tell Ocelot to use Consul instead of Host:Port?**

If you have a moment, I’d appreciate your help.